# Listening to a CustomEvent from another file

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with some legacy code which is dispatching a custom event like so:

```
    class AuthStatus {
     constructor() {
      this.init();
    }
    async init() {
    const event = new CustomEvent("qwerty-authentication", {
          detail: {
            isLoggedIn,
            sessionId,
            submittedEmail,
            user,
          },
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    }
export default AuthStatus;
```

But how can I listen for the event triggering **from another file**? Is that even possible? Everytime I run: `window.addEventListener('qwerty-authentication', (e) => console.log(e));` it's always undefined, but if I run it in the same file I **do** get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addEventListener` to listen to that event, as the event applied to the `window` `window.dispatchEvent(event);`, so you need.

```
window.addEventListener('qwerty-authentication', function () {
  console.log('event fired');
})
```

Comment: Hi, to which file? And does it need to be declared before or after window.dispatchEvent(event);?

Comment: As any file in the application can use window, any file can listen to that event. it should be declared before you `dispatch` the event.